# Vedanta and prayer

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, prayer

Is praying, and asking a God for things, useful/beneficial in advaita védanta? Since Isvara is considered to be only conceptually true, and ultimately non-existent, can he really be helpful?

Comment: Advaita roots are oneness of finite being and infinite existence, not atheism. Ishvara is called Brahman or Atman or Higher Self in advaita, while jiva is lower self connected to material body via mind. If advaitain was perfect he wouldn't have manifested in world in first place, perfection of jiva Prakriti is to be attained with the aid of higher Self Purusha. “Two birds of beautiful plumage closely united in friendship reside on the same tree.One of them eats the sweet fruit thereof, the other witnesses without eating.- Mundaka Upanishad (III.1.2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jivatva

Comment: Union of jiva Prakriti and ishwara Purusha is what's called yoga(union) or Self-realization.